# how to fill complete screen with differnt views in android

Tags: android, textview, imagebutton

I have simple question but this is making my development terrible.

in different activities i have different set of views. for example textview, buttonview, editview. what i want is, all views should be fit dynamically on screen (no matter i have one view or 5 views)  but its not happening. some time views go out side the screen and some times white space left on screen.

bellow is what i tried, i do not want to provide android:layout_height="75dp".

Please F1

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btnmusic"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/btnselectedsong" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnpause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/btnplay"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btnpause"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnpause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btnstop"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use a `RelativeLayout` as the base.

Answer (score 0):

set `layout_weight=1` to all the wiews, which you want to share available space equally.

for your code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="odp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btnmusic"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="odp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="odp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/btnselectedsong" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnpause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/btnplay"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btnpause"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnpause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btnstop"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="odp"
            android:layout_weight="1"            
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Shailendra when i apply  picture as background it does not work other wise it works.. but i "must have" picture as background on button and all views

Answer (score 0):

If you use a relative layout you can define features in respect to the edges of the screen and the horizontal and vertical centers allowing for a dynamic placment of the buttons.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btnmusic"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner1"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
....
....
....
</RelativeLayout>
```

Something like that should give you a dynamic layout.

Comment: chefburns can you elaborte your answer with you some example

Answer (score 0):

As you are using LinearLayout so you can use layout_weight that will take care of adjusting whole space.

If you want to give specific space apart from equal spacing you can define a **android:weightSum="100"**
and can distribute it to child layout according to your requirement

I simply tried with some demo and changed your layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:android:weightSum="100" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/btnmusic"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


        </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10" >

           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
          </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="40" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/btnselectedsong" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnpause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/btnplay"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="30" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btnpause"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnpause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btnstop"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="10" >
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
       </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Your solution only works if i do not apply picture as background. but linear layout stretchs as per picture size. :(

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Have a `LinearLayout` as Parent
> 2. Set its `layout_height="fill_parent"` and `orientation="horizontal"`
> 3. Add the the `views` you have, to this parent
> 4. Finally to every view set `layout_weight="1"`

By the last line you mean, no matter how many view you have, they all must be of equal height and by 1st line you mean, all together, the views must occupy the whole screen.